# Assign subroutine output to a variable or call a subroutine as an argument of another subroutine

Tags: fortran

I am looking to have a subroutine be called and use what is called from there to be put into another subroutine. The setup is similar to what I have below and I want to either have the output of a subroutine be assigned to a variable or use the output as an argument inside of a different calling of a subroutine.

```
program start
  implicit none
  character(len=40) :: arg1, arg2, input1, input2, input3
  arg1 = "file_name.txt"
  input1 = "Some input"
  input2 = "More input"
  input3 = "Final input"
  ! I either want this below
  arg2 = call two(input1, input2, input3)

  call one(arg1, 12, arg2)

  ! Or this
  call one(arg1, 12, call two(input1, input2, input3))

end program start

subroutine one(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  implicit none
  character(len=40) :: arg1, arg2, arg3
  open(arg1, arg2)
  write(arg2, '(a)') arg3
end subroutine one

subroutine two(input1, input2, input3)
  implicit none
  character(len=40) :: input1, input2, input3
  character(len=120) :: output
  output = input1 // NEW_LINE('A') // input2 // NEW_LINE('A') // input3
   
end subroutine two
```

Comment: Why isn't `two` a function?  As `output` is a local variable it has a rather misleading name.

Comment: Hmmm, this code is quite a mess.  A subroutine is not a function.  `call` is used to invoke a subroutine.  It is a statement that does not return anything.  You're also missing an `end program start` statement.  You use the `number` and it's not defined.

Comment: @francescalus I'll be honest, I didn't think of that.

Comment: @steve There are certainly some mistakes in the format but that is because I didn't copy and paste it over. I edited the problem so it should show it correctly. This is just a very generic version of the script.

Comment: It is so messed up, with 35+ years of Fortran coding experience, I cannot tell what this code is suppose to do.  None of `input1`, `input2`, or `input3` has a value, so we're guessing at what valid input is.  In additional, your `open` statement needs to keywords.

Comment: @steve making two a function rather than a subroutine fixed the issues though you are right that I forgot to input the values I had for inputs 1-3 but they were just strings. My open has the argument of the name given by arg1 and the number after when I call one. Though I can admit in my attempt to simplify this script I over simplified and named things too generically and messed up my post. Either way, turning my `subroutine two` into a `function` fixed the issue and I honestly just spaced on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fortran the syntax for the `call` statement for calling a subroutine is simply `call <subroutine name>([arg1[,arg2[...]]])`, no other usages are allowed as far as I remember.

What you have in your mind, as remarked in the notes, is probably a `function`, which in fortran is invoked without the `call` keyword, it returns a single variable as a result (possibly an array or a derived type or a combination of them) and the result is syntactically usable in an expression and thus as an argument to another function or subroutine call.

Something in the lines of (sorry for the different use of upper/lower case, that's a matter of style):

```
PROGRAM funfun
CALL p3(f1(f2(4.)))
END PROGRAM funfun

REAL FUNCTION f1(x)
REAL,INTENT(in) :: x
f1 = x**2
END FUNCTION f1

REAL FUNCTION f2(x)
REAL,INTENT(in) :: x
f2 = x**3
END FUNCTION f2

SUBROUTINE p3(x)
REAL,INTENT(in) :: x
PRINT*,'The result is',x
END SUBROUTINE p3
```

By the way, in your program you are already making use of the (intrinsic) function `NEW_LINE`.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the example!